# Fish Shell – how to make a function ask for input before COMPLETING the function

Tags: fish

I created a function named `pushall` that runs

```
git add .
git commit -m "$argv"
git push
```

however when I run I get the following error

`Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`

how can make the function ask me for input to enter into the commit message so that the function works as intended?

Comment: _Before_ running? Why not put that code at the top of the _inside_ of the function, so it happens _while_ running?

Comment: ...it would be typical to, say, assign a local variable from `$argv` when your argv is nonempty; and prompt for a value to that variable otherwise.

Comment: ...also, while I'm rather pointedly and intentionally not an expert on fish, in POSIX-compliant shells you can change a function's argument list after that function is already running. It's plausible (though by no means certain) that fish may have similar functionality.

Comment: (BTW, a quick note on tagging -- thing of tags as a way to attract experts on thing-X to your question; there's no such thing as an expert on functions, since how they work is slightly different in every language, so `function` isn't a very useful tag; similarly, if a generic person who groks most shells won't be helpful towards answering your fish question, leave off the shell tag and just stick to the fish tag).

Comment: `git commit` *already* asks you for a commit message if you don't use `-m`, and it lets you use the editor of your choice to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
function pushall
    git add .

    if test (count $argv) -eq 0
        git commit
    else
        git commit -m "$argv"
    end

    git push
end
```